# Using Functions for Easy writing makes SQL really slow

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create or replace FUNCTION FUNCTION_X
(
  N_STRING IN VARCHAR2 
) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
BEGIN
  RETURN UPPER(translate(N_STRING, 'ÁÇÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÂÊÎÔÛÃÕËÜáçéíóúàèìòùâêîôûãõëü','ACEIOUAEIOUAEIOUAOEUaceiouaeiouaeiouaoeu'));
END FUNCTION_X;
```

SELECT takes around 5 seconds (80k + Lines)

```
SELECT TABLE_A.STRING_X
FROM TABLE_A
INNER JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_B.ID = TABLE_A.IDTB
WHERE
   UPPER(UPPER(translate(TABLEB.STRING_X, 
   'ÁÇÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÂÊÎÔÛÃÕËÜáçéíóúàèìòùâêîôûãõëü','ACEIOUAEIOUAEIOUAOEUaceiouaeiouaeiouaoeu'))
   =
   UPPER(translate(TABLEB.N_STRING, 
   'ÁÇÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÂÊÎÔÛÃÕËÜáçéíóúàèìòùâêîôûãõëü','ACEIOUAEIOUAEIOUAOEUaceiouaeiouaeiouaoeu')
```

Using function takes over 3 minutes (80k + lines)

```
SELECT TABLE_A.STRING_X
    FROM TABLE_A
    INNER JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_B.ID = TABLE_A.IDTB
    WHERE
       FUNCTION_X(TABLE_A.STRING_X) = FUNCTION_X(TABLE_B.N_STRING)
```

I dont know whats makes it so heavy.

Comment: Functional calls as `JOIN` conditions are going to kill performance.  You could build an index on the expression, though.

Comment: Pragma udf can help a little bit, but anyway context switches are expensive

Comment: Full Edit:
I use this function because in brazilian portugues we have a heavy use o accentuation. if i join using 'SÃO PAULO' = 'SAO PAULO' it will give no match. so not to write the whole expression on a JOIN i tought on creating  function, but its too expensive

Comment: You might want to read up on [accent-insensitive and linguistic sorting and matching](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/nlspg/linguistic-sorting-and-matching.html#GUID-7FF18E5A-4ED6-4BDC-8059-886E9BD85E8F).

Comment: Can you post the execution plan of both statements? Run `explain plan for select ...` and then `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);`. I bet the functions are not *directly* the cause of the problem - even executing the function a million times shouldn't take more than a few seconds. There's already another join condition between the two tables, maybe the function somehow confuses Oracle about the number of rows returned, and that changes the execution plan to use a different join method.

Answer (score 2):

If your first query, with the `UPPER(UPPER(translate(...)))` inline in the query takes only 5 seconds and the tables are big, I would look to see if you have a function based index having those functions on either or both tables.

An index, as you probably know, stores a sorted version of the data so that rows can be found quickly.  But they're only useful if you are searching on the data that is sorted in the index.  (Think of an index in a book, in which keywords sorted alphabetically -- useful for searching for a particular word, not so useful for finding references to words ending in the letter "r").

If there is a function based index on `UPPER(UPPER(translate(...)))` that is helping your original query, you are losing the benefit when your query specifies `FUNCTION_X(...)` instead.  Oracle is not smart enough to realize they are the same function.  You would need to create function based indexes on the expression you actually use in the query -- i.e, on `FUNCTION_X(...)`.

Also, you can help performance by telling Oracle that your function is deterministic (i.e., always returns the same value for the same input) and intended to be used in SQL queries.  So, in addition to the function based indexes, a better definition of your function would be:

```
create or replace FUNCTION FUNCTION_X
(
  N_STRING IN VARCHAR2 
) RETURN VARCHAR2 
DETERMINISTIC -- add this
AS 
PRAGMA UDF;   -- add this too
BEGIN
  RETURN UPPER(translate(N_STRING, 'ÁÇÉÍÓÚÀÈÌÒÙÂÊÎÔÛÃÕËÜáçéíóúàèìòùâêîôûãõëü','ACEIOUAEIOUAEIOUAOEUaceiouaeiouaeiouaoeu'));
END FUNCTION_X;
```

Answer (score 0):

`JOINS`, of course, intend to exploit index values.  The problem with your second query is that you are demanding that the SQL engine must execute this function-call for each and every line. It therefore cannot do anything better than a "full table scan," evaluating the function over each and every row ... actually over a *Cartesian Product* of the two tables taken together!!

You must find an alternative way to do that.

Comment: The first one would not use an index either, as all columns in the WHERE clause are also "hidden" in a function call as well